# Why is fprem1 instruction not producing the expected results?

Tags: assembly, fpu, x87, hla, remainder

In the book of the art of assembly language, it is said that:

> The fprem1 instruction computes a partial remainder. fprem1 computes the partial remainder of st0/st1. If the difference between the exponents of ST0 and ST1 is less than 64, fprem1 can compute the exact
> remainder in one operation.

ST0 and ST1 are the FPU data registers. so I wanted to test its performance.
My code is like this:

```
program  exercise;

#include( "stdlib.hhf" );
static
          x: real80:=156.5e18;//first number
          y: real80:=14.36;  //second number
          z:real80;  // partial remainder
begin exercise;
     fld(y);    //y goes into st0
     fld(x);    //now x goes into st0 but previous content of st0 
                //(that is st1) will move into st1, so x is into st0 and y is into st1
     fprem1();  //calculates the remainder of st0/st1 (here x/y )but 
                // for getting the remainder, the quotient will round to the nearest value and then
                //  remainder = st0 - rounded quotient*st1==>>that is
                // equivalent by remainder= x-rounded quotient*y 
                //  ===>> then the remainder  can be positive or negative.
     fstp(z);   //this will store the partial remainder in the z real80 variable.
     stdout.put("z:  ",z); 
end  exercise;
```

But when I run this program, realized that for small power differences, the results It can be expected, but for larger differences, the results are far from expected.

```
 I have summarized my result below:
      dividing               expected remainder     program remainder
     *****************************************************************      
1)    156.5/14.36                  -1.46          -1.4599..9e000
2)    156.5e1/14.36                -.24           -2.39e-1
3)    156.5e2/14.36                -2.4           -2.39
4)    156.5e3/14.36                 4.72           4.7200...619
5)    156.5e4/14.36                 4.12           4.1200...6195
6)    156.5e5/14.36                -1.88          -1.8799...805
7)    156.5e6/14.36                -4.44          -4.4399..3805
8)    156.5e7/14.36                -1.32          -1.3199...5017
9)    156.5e8/14.36                 1.16           1.16006..826
10)   156.5e9/14.36                -2.76          -2.7599..737
11)   156.5e10/14.36                1.12           1.1200619..627
12)   156.5e11/14.36               -3.16          -3.159380..739
13)   156.5e12/14.36               -2.88          -2.873805..346
14)   156.5e13/14.36               -0.08          -7.99..e-2  ~= -0.079
15)   156.5e14/14.36               -0.8           -7.99..e-1  ~= -0.79
16)   156.5e15/14.36                6.36           6.36340...924
17)   156.5e16/14.36                6.16           6.1940300..120
18)   156.5e17/14.36                4.16           4.500300559
        /***** unacceptable results (from program) at bellow *****/
19)   156.5e18/14.36       (expected) 1.48          5.13274..e10                      
20)   156.5e19/14.36       (expected) 0.44          5.13274..e10 
 
     ****************************************************************   
The Results 19) and 20) is unacceptable, because the remainder can not 
  be greater than divisor, which is incorrect.
>>Am I doing wrong? Or is there a problem with this instruction(fprem1)?
Can someone explain my problem? What can I do? Thanks.
```

Comment: The manual (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fprem1) says it can reduce the exponent of `ST(0)` by no more than 63 in one execution of the instruction, and that it does iterative subtraction (presumably of scaled values).  So if you want a full (not partial) remainder, you should run it in a loop until the C2 FPU status flag is clear.

Comment: That's why the mnemonic is fprem (partial remainder), not frem.

Comment: Your question's quote from the book includes the critical phrase: **If the difference between the exponents of ST0 and ST1 is less than 64,**...  They're talking about the base-2 exponent of the binary floating-point numbers, not base-10 exponents like 1e18.  In fact log2(1e18) ~= 59.76, and `log2(156.5/14.36)` is 3.446.  But exponent values have to be integers in IEEE floating point, so yeah, clearly they differ by 64 not 63 in that case, so the remainder is only *partial* when the dividend is that large.

Comment: @PeterCordes The full text of the book in this section is like this: <<If the difference between the exponents of ST0 and ST1 is less than 64, fprem1 can compute the exact remainder in one operation. Otherwise you will have to execute the fprem1 two or more times to get the correct remainder value.>> My question is: the power difference of 18, 19, and above is still far from 64, So, according to the book, the correct answer should be found by using fprem1() once, not by using this command several times.

Comment: @PeterCordesThank you for your explanation. Can you make this more clear? I need to know more about how this command works.

Comment: It sounds like it's not this instruction that you need to know more about, it's binary floating-point in general.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format